# Find oldest date from structure array (C code)

Tags: arrays, c, date, compare

First of all I'm kinda new to c.

I have this structure that is a dynamic array and its where *onlineClasses* are stored.
Each *onlineClass* have a date and also three states(Scheduled,Running or Finished).

```
typedef struct{

    int day,month,year;

} typeDate;
```

```
typedef struct{

    typeDate date;

    int state;


} onlineClass;
```

Just to give some more context (if state ==3 the class is scheduled, if its == 2 its Finished and if its == 1 means its Running);

Ok now going to the point, I'd like to know how can I output the oldest date from that array which state is "Finished"(state ==2);

I'd like to know if someone could help me with the code or give me some ideas of how it  can  be done.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Firstly, that is not an array. It's not even a variable. It is a type. But if you did have an array then you would write a loop that iterates over the array. Init a variable with the first element and use that as the current oldest date. Then for each subsequent element compare it with the current oldest one and record it if it is the new oldest.

Comment: I was just giving some context to the problem, I have hundreds of lines of code not only creating the array itself, allocating memory,etc. I just didnt feel like I needed to post all the code here and just give some context to what I was looking.

Comment: @kaylum And I know what you are saying, in my head I also have that idea, I just dont know how to rly put it into code.

Comment: So what exactly is the difficulty? Do you know how to write a `for` loop to iterate over each array element? Do you know how to compare the data of two elements? Do you know how to store the current oldest element? What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @kaylum if I had to work only with the date I guess what you are saying sounds pretty simple, but I also have to work around the fact that the state has to be (finished).

Comment: Just check the state and only compare the date if the current element is in the right state: `if (class_array[i].state == 2 ) { /* do date comparison */ } `

Comment: I think this `{typeDate;` is `typeDate};`